# How to trigger an animate text when hover on a text/image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

My brand name is: Code

My `nav` look like this

> Code                Home |  Service | Product |  Contact

I want to change `Code` -> `{ Code }` when users hover on my my brand name.

I want to style the `{ }` to have `red` color.

I want the `{ }` to slide right in no later than `2` seconds.

Can someone tell me how can I do that in `CSS` ?

Will I need `JS` for that due to animation involve ?

`Edit`

Direction of animate

{<-- Code   -->}

Comment: slide from the right? They would just slide in from the nowhere?

Comment: {<-- Code   -->} I kind of want it go out of the word `Code`. You know what I mean.

Comment: so the {} appear on hover just as underline

Comment: @skv : As underline ? Wait.. I'm a little confuse, what do you mean by that ? I don't want any underline sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this. You can use CSS's `transitions` to create some nice effects

```
<div class="logo">
  <span class="left">{</span>
  Code
  <span class="right">}</span>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6rf2tfxt/)

Comment: @jmore009. Your solution is also work too :) . Thank you both of you so much ! :)

Comment: Very well answer - jmore009

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rLdtse86/13/

You use [Pseudo elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) on hover action

```
a:hover::before
{
    content:"{";
}

a:hover::after
{
    content:"}";
}
```

Comment: Do you mind edit your code a little bit and explain the different of ::after and ::before ?, I will make sure to except it.

Comment: did I understand your requirement

Comment: Yes. You did it well !

Comment: @evoque2015 - this is what using `a:before` and `a:after` is the same as: `<a><span>{</span>Content inside<span>}</span></a>`. The before is placed inside the element before any other contents and the after is placed inside the element after any other contents. This is a great option for decorative CSS. You could use the single colon `:before` and it will be supported in IE8+ and all modern browsers.